# util.inspect Default depth is should be 20, but appears smaller

Tags: node.js

## Code

Consider the following Node.js code:

```js
const { inspect } = require('util');

const obj = { response: [ { webhooks: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ] };

console.log(`Obj is ${obj}`);
console.log(`Obj is ${inspect(obj, { breakLength: Infinity })}`);
console.log(`Obj is ${inspect(obj, { breakLength: Infinity, depth: 20 })}`);
console.log(`Obj is ${inspect(obj, { breakLength: Infinity, depth: Infinity })}`);
```

Gives:

```bash
Obj is [object Object]
Obj is { response: [ { webhooks: [Array] } ] }
Obj is { response: [ { webhooks: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ] }
Obj is { response: [ { webhooks: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } ] }
```

## The Problem

According to the [manual](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

> depth  Specifies the number of times to recurse while formatting the object. This is useful for inspecting large complicated objects. To make it recurse up to the maximum call stack size pass Infinity or null. Default: 20.

As far as I understand it, the second `console.log` line should print the entire same string as the third, because the default for `depth` is 20. Alas, it prints `[Array]` instead of `[ 1, 2, 3 ]`.

## My Question

Why doesn't the default call behave like `depth: 20`?

Answer (score 1):

Silly me.

On the latest versions, the default value [is changed](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/7082c61e27142c1c4c55ab925baa8a162637b066) from [2](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/util.html) to [20](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/util.html). I was reading the documentation for v11 and used v8.